# Removing duplicates in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Hi everyone i've been trying for days now to remove from my db all the duplicates that are in it. I've tried this solution that I found at this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072209/mongodb-duplicate-documents-even-after-adding-unique-key) or at this one which is almost the same but unfortunately it returns the error that forEach is not a function. I don't understand why for them works and not for me even if the code is almost the same. Here's the code that i've tried so far

```
exports = function(payload, response) {
  const mongodb = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas");
  var obj=EJSON.parse(payload.body.text())
  var inserimentoDB = mongodb.db("test").collection("test0").insertMany(obj)
  var duplicates = [];
  mongodb.db("test").collection("test0").aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { "Val": "$Val" },
        "dups": { "$push": "$_id" },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$match": { "count": { "$gt": 1 } }}
]).toArray().forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.dups.shift();
    mongodb.db("test").collection("test0").remove({ "_id": {"$in": doc.dups }});
});
  }
```

I'm executing this code in a stitch function

Comment: How do you define "duplicate" and what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I mean that there are more than one elements in db with the same value on a attribute

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still an issue for you, but I had a similar issue. Using MongoDB Atlas service, what worked for me was to first test out the aggregation in the aggregation widget to make sure I was getting the expected results. Then I had reformat your code a bit and use `.then()` instead of `.forEach()`.

so for your case, the final solution would look something like this:

```
collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { "Val": "$Val" },
        "dups": { "$push": "$_id" },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$match": { "count": { "$gt": 1 } }}
]).toArray().then(data => {
    var dr = data.map(d => d.name);
    console.log("duplicate Records:: ", data);
    
    collection.remove({ id: { $in: dr } }).then(removedD => {
        console.log("Removed duplicate Data:: ", removedD);
    })
});
```