# Push object to a mongoose array and check for duplicate fields inside the array objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to push a notification object to a mongoDB array with the follow condition:

Check if there is a notification inside the array with the same postId 
**If yes:** return that object
**If no:** create a new notification object

I'm using node with Mongoose ODM. In some other questions online they give this as an answer:

```
user.update({'notifications.postId': {$ne: post._id}}, {$push: { 'notifications': {type: 'POST', postId: post._id}}}, function(err, doc) {
  .....
});
```

But this didn't work for me.

Below you find the structure of the mongodb document.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "56631b22067ee41847dab6bb"
    },
    "unreadNotifications": 0,
    "notifications": [
      {
        "type": "POST",
        "postId": {
          "$oid": "5666b78b61eb95bc03d47a71"
        },
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "56782daa395840efd4ed3f7a"
        },
        "createdAt": {
          "$date": "2015-12-21T16:49:46.903Z"
        },
        "events": []
      }    
    ]
    "created": {
        "$date": "2015-12-05T17:13:06.782Z"
    },
    "lastName": "Power",
    "firstName": "John",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help @DavidGrinberg

Comment: Not sure what you're doing is possible in a single query

Comment: @BobS Can you update your question to include your schema? That's key in figuring out why what you're trying isn't working.

Comment: you can try the answers given in this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190370/how-to-remove-duplicates-based-on-a-key-in-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

Note that `Schema#update` method will not updating records because there are no matched records described by specified match condition.

Anyway, You can create your own method on your User Schema.

### Example

```
UserSchema.method('sendNotification', function (post, done) {
    var notification = null;

    for (var i = 0, len = this.notifications.length ; i < len ; i++) {
        notification = this.notifications[i];
        if (notification.postId.equals(post._id)) {
            return done(null, notification);
        }
    }

    notification = {
        type: 'POST',
        postId: post._id
    };

    this.update({
        $push: {
            notifications: notification
        }
    }, function (e, doc) {
        if (e) { return done(e); }
        return done(null, notification);
    });
});
```

You can use this method after model was created.

```
User.findOne({
    email: 'john@example.com'
}).exec(function (e, john) {
    john.sendNotification(post, function (e, notification) {
        if (e) { console.log('Ah snap! There are an error.'); }
        console.log('notification: ', notification);
    });
});
```