# Remove duplicate documents based on field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've seen a number of solutions on this, however they are all for Mongo v2 and are not suitable for V3.

My document looks like this:

```
    { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("582c98667d81e1d0270cb3e9"), 
    "asin" : "B01MTKPJT1", 
    "url" : "https://www.amazon.com/Trump-President-Presidential-Victory-T-Shirt/dp/B01MTKPJT1%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIVCW62S7NTZ2U2AQ%26tag%3Dselfbalancingscooters-21%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB01MTKPJT1", 
    "image" : "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41RvN8ud6UL.jpg", 
    "salesRank" : NumberInt(442137), 
    "title" : "Trump Wins 45th President Presidential Victory T-Shirt", 
    "brand" : "\"Getting Political On Me\"", 
    "favourite" : false, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-11-16T17:33:26.763+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-11-16T17:33:26.763+0000")
}
```

and my collection contains around 500k documents.  I want to remove all duplicate documents (except for 1) where the ASIN is the same

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36099237/122005)?

Comment: @chridam I don't like that answer. It is not the way to go(

Comment: Which of the document to you intend to keep? The last created or updated?

Comment: @Styvane It doesn't really matter to be honest as the content for the rest of it is identical (apart from id, createdAt, updatedAt)

Comment: @Styvane Not the best considering the OP's db size but the concept of sorting could suffice. Could be better optimised by leveraging Bulk API methods instead of the collection's `remove()` method.

Comment: @chridam Would I not have to find all the duplicate asin's with that first?  I ran the following but I just get ...
 ```db.merch-tracker.find({},{asin:1}).sort({_id:1}).forEach(function(doc){db.tee.remove({_id:{$gt:doc._id},asin:doc.asin});```

Comment: I think the best way to go is use the aggregation framework to get a list of `_id`s of the duplicate documents, iterate the list and use the bulk API's `removeOne()` method to delete each duplicate document in batches. By the way, what version is your MongoDB server?

Comment: Are you aware of the different collections in this operation `db.merch-tracker.find({},{asin:1}).sort({_id:1}).forEach(fun‌​ction(doc){db.tee.re‌​move({_id:{$gt:doc._‌​id},asin:doc.asin});`? You are trying to delete documents in the `tee` collection with id's from `tracker` collection which obviously will fail since the `_id`s are unique in both collections.

Comment: Yeah I've just changed it as I noticed that.  I now have ```db.tee.find({}, {asin:1}).sort({_id:1}).forEach(function(doc){db.tee.remove{(_id:{$gt:doc._id},asin:doc.asin})```   Same thing though :(

Comment: OK, that function does not work.  It seems to remove everything, even none dupes

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is something we can actually do using the aggregation framework and without client side processing.

#### MongoDB 3.4

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [ 
        { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }, 
        { "$group": { 
            "_id": "$asin", 
            "doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" } 
        }}, 
        { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$doc" } },
        { "$out": "collection" }
    ]

)
```

#### MongoDB version <= 3.2:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [ 
        { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }, 
        { "$group": { 
            "_id": "$asin", 
            "doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" } 
        }}, 
        { "$project": { 
            "asin": "$doc.asin", 
            "url": "$doc.url", 
            "image": "$doc.image", 
            "salesRank": "$doc.salesRank", 
            "title": "$doc.salesRank", 
            "brand": "$doc.brand", 
            "favourite": "$doc.favourite", 
            "createdAt": "$doc.createdAt", 
            "updatedAt": "$doc.updatedAt" 
        }},
        { "$out": "collection" }
    ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I did something wrong in the query - I ran the first one and all my collection is gone :/ Saying this just in case somebody runs it without backup

Comment: I use the MongoDB 3.4 and it works like a charm, thanks a lot. Very easy to add more keys like this `'_id': {"country":"$country", 
                                "city":"$city", 
                                'language':"$language"
                                }`

Comment: Drop [`{ "$out": "collection" }`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) if you don't want to overwrite the current collection (e.g. to use as a query), or use `{"$out": "newcollection"}` to create a new collection (named "newcollection").

Comment: @styvane Why the `{ "$sort": { "_id": 1 }}` step ?  It doesn't seem necessary ?

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou this is because we want to maintain the oldest version for each document. And the `_id` which in this case is an [`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid) is based on timestamp.

Comment: Spectacular answer! Saved a ton of my time. To be honest, a more concrete example should be placed on MongoDB's docs in implementing $replaceRoot and $$ROOT

Answer (score 3):

Use a for loop, it will take time but will do the work

```
db.amazon_sales.find({}, {asin:1}).sort({_id:1}).forEach(function(doc){
    db.amazon_sales.remove({_id:{$gt:doc._id}, asin:doc.asin});
})
```

Then and this index

```
db.amazon_sales.createIndex( { "asin": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```