# How to remove duplicates based on a condition in Mongodb?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5d3acf79ea99ef80dca9bcca"), 
"memberId" : "123",
"generatedId" : "00000d2f-9922-457a-be23-731f5fefeb14",
"memberType" : "premium"
},

{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e01554cea99eff7f98d7eed"), 
"memberId" : "123",
"generatedId" : "34jkd2092sdlk02kl23kl2309k2309kr",
"memberType" : "premium"
}
```

I have 1 million docs like this format and how can i remove duplicated docs based on "memberId". 
I need to be remove the duplicated docs where the "generatedId" value do not contain "-". In this example it should be deleted the bottom doc since it does not contains "-" in the "generatedId" value.
Can someone share any idea how to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicate documents based on field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40654446/remove-duplicate-documents-based-on-field)

Comment: not really@radulle...In my case the doc where the  "generatedId" value do not contain "-" to be removed.looking thoughts on this.

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: Ok I understand, why not than just first select only those that do not have "-" and than filter duplicates and use those "_id"s to remove  them?

Comment: You brought good point...But the docs are unique if i can filter the docs where "-" is existed and also the docs are unique if i can filter where "-" is not existed. But the problem is both patterns are mixed and i need to be drop the duplicated records only where the "-" is not existed(if found).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there can be a strategy, but still, it depends on your data a lot.

Let's say you take your docs. Group them by their Id's for counting (duplicates), and then from the duplicates separate out all those entries where generatedId does not contain hyphens "-". When you get these docs which are duplicates and also does not contain - in their generatedId, you can delete them.

```
const result = await Collection.aggregate([
{
    $project: {
        _id: 1, // keep the _id field where it is anyway
        doc: "$$ROOT", // store the entire document in the "doc" field
    },
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$doc.memberId", // group by the documents by memeberId
        count: { $sum: 1 }, // count the number of documents in this group
        generatedId: { $first: "$doc.generatedId" }, // for keeping these values to be passed to other stages
        memberType: { $first: "$doc.memberType" }, //  for keeping these values to be passed to other stages
    },
},
{
    $match: {
        count: { $gt: 1 }, // only show what's duplicated because it'll have count greater than 1

        // It'll match all those documents not having - in them
        generatedId: { $regex: /^((?!-).)*$/g } / g,
    },
},
]);
```

Now in the result, you'll have docs which were memberId duplicates and does not have - in their generatedId. You can query them for deletion.

**Warning**: 
Depending on your data it's possible certain duplicated memberId does not have '-' at all in their generatedIds, so you might delete all docs.

Always take backup before performing operations that might behave uncertain way.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{ 
 // first match all records with having - in generatedId
 "$match" : { "generatedId" : { "$regex": "[-]"} } },

 // then group them
  { 
   "$group": { 
        "_id": "$memberId", 
  }}

])
```

Comment: why we need to be group them individually?? Its a mixed data with and without "-" combination. If we find more then one record with the same member Id where generatedId is contains either "-" or without hyphen, then we need to remove non-hyphen doc.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation

Comment: @BhanuMakineni, I'm sorry I got your problem a bit wrong.