# Mongo bulk insert duplicate _id

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to bulk insert documents and I'm creating the _id. 
Is there a way to bulk over write the existing documents with new documents if _id matches?

Comment: Mongo index has a feature to drop duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190370/how-to-remove-duplicates-based-on-a-key-in-mongodb

Comment: dropDups is dropped long time ago and is not available in any maintainable versions of the db. Use bulk upserts instead https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#updateone-and-updatemany

Comment: Say this is my first insert.
{ "_id" : 1, "char" : "Brisbane", "class" : "monk", "lvl" : 4 },
{ "_id" : 2, "char" : "Eldon", "class" : "alchemist", "lvl" : 3 },
My use case is to override the existing values .  The following insert shouldn't throw error but overwrite the char fields
{ "_id" : 1, "char" : "England", "class" : "monk", "lvl" : 4 },
{ "_id" : 2, "char" : "Scotland", "class" : "alchemist", "lvl" : 3 },

Comment: Did you tried MongoDB db.collection.update(query,dataToUpdate, option) function with option {upsert: true}. It will first find the document and update if exist or insert a new document if the query does not match.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option

Comment: Update: Nothing of this sort exists as per the current mongo functionality.